# Can I skip levels to get the "no damage" achievements?

Tags: achievements, the-binding-of-isaac

Several items in the *Binding of Isaac* allow you to skip a level without facing the boss (*We Need to Go Deeper* and the *Teleport!* item, though teleporting is a less reliable form of level skipping).

I've managed to get all "no damage" achievements except the one for *The Depths*, mainly due to the abundance of *Leapers* on those levels. Whenever I unlocked one of said achievements, it was always the instant I defeated the boss on the second floor for that level, making it seem like the two are tied together.

So I was wondering, suppose I simply skip through the second level without having incurred damage on the first (possibly skipping some or most of it as well), will I still get the achievement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, you cannot. Sadly, the achievement only registers on the boss kills, and not by going further down the dungeon.

Comment: Well, I guess that is to be expected of such a fiendish game.

Comment: Actually, you can skip the first level boss, but you need to face the second.